# Unnecessary Certificate Authority in Domain

Tags: windows, domain-controller, certificate-authority

I have an organization with a file server that is a secondary domain controller(2003 R2), an Exchange server(2008 R2), and a primary domain controller(2008 R2).  We also have what used to be the primary domain controller, but has been demoted to be the third domain controller(2003).

I am wanting to remove this last one entirely, but am worried it will cause issues.  Many years ago, someone set this server up as a Certificate Authority, I believe trying to do something with email encryption that never panned out.  It currently only has 3 valid certificates issues, one to each of the domain controllers.

I am not at all familiar with the CA role.  Can I simply revoke the three issued certificates and then remove the role, or will that cause some kind of unforeseen problem?

Comment: Explain some more about how you think you demoted the 3rd DC to its present role.

Comment: One of the other servers has been made the Global Catalog Server and the FSMO roles have been transferred to it.  The domain itself is healthy.  I'm just unsure about the Certificate Authority role and what repercussions there might be by removing it.

Comment: I'm making a point about your terminology which has been out-of-use since NT 4.0 - PDC Emulator is only one FSMO role and it's holder is not the "primary domain controller". The FSMO roles can be spread out amongst multiple servers. Any, or all, servers can be GC servers. None of those things are "demotions", so please don't say that.

Comment: What I meant is that it is no longer the primary DC.  Do you have any helpful advice in relation to my question?

Comment: I have done so. When you're operating in an environment of professionals, it's a good idea to not use terminology that is both old and wrong - it makes it look like you don't know your technology as well as might be hoped for. It's a learning opportunity, that you don't want to turn your nose up at.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't certain whether those issued certs are used by anything, then you can do this in a phased approach.

Revoke the certs, ensure that the DCs know that they've been revoked (using the Certificates MMC snap-in on each DC), and then wait a few weeks.

If nothing breaks, then go ahead and remove the CA role.

Comment: More advice can be found in the following places: http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/889250 http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771494.aspx